# Make multiple WebBrowser's without dragging them in file

Tags: vb.net

Ok, so a program I am making involves using multiple webbrowsers with different cookies. It logs into the same site on several accounts. However, to log into several sites I need multiple webbrowsers running the same function, but I want this program to be able to log into as many accounts as needed, so I need to generate a webbrowser basically. Instead of putting it in the form, I need a code that generates a webbrowser on the form. Is this even possible?

Comment: Why are you attempting to log into many accounts on the same site?

Comment: It's for my website, and I need this done so I can test how many users can be logged in at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Load` event of the form to create `new WebBrowser()` controls and `Add` them to the Form's `Controls` collection.

However, it is not necessary to add them to the form in order to use them.

[WebBrowser :MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)

Comment: You should post the errors that you received. However, David has advised of a more significant issue for your circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically create many WebBrowsers but it wont work the way that you want. Each WebBrowser will act like a separate tab of an Internet Explorer. For more information you can check the following.

[Hosting multiple WebBrowser controls in one window causes sessions to "cross": any solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803888/hosting-multiple-webbrowser-controls-in-one-window-causes-sessions-to-cross-a).

Comment: So there is no way around that? :\

Comment: I suppose you could attempt to clear cookies each time [SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912741/c-webbrowser-control-how-to-delete-cookies-from-windows-form) but I am not convinced about how effective this might be. I am suspicious that, if it could work, you would need to wait, and close/remove, each WB instance.

Comment: Check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Center_Test maybe it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tabcontrol and put each webbrowser in a separate tabpage.  You can easily declare a tabpage with a webbrowser and add or remove the tabpage as needed. Since each document that the webbrowser loads has it's own cookie collection, and the website is your own, you should be able to set up your website to accept multiple users from the same machine, at least temporarily for testing.